# How to set different text colours on uitableviews

Tags: uitableview, text, colors

I have a dynamic `UITableview` and I want to set different text colours for each cell.

What code would i need to make the text colours be red, yellow, green, blue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the following code will help you

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row % 4 == 0)
        cell.textLabel.textColor =[UIColor redColor];
    else if(indexPath.row % 4 == 1)
        cell.textLabel.textColor =[UIColor blueColor];
    else if (indexPath.row % 4 == 2)
        cell.textLabel.textColor =[UIColor yellowColor];
    else if (indexPath.row % 4 == 2)
        cell.textLabel.textColor =[UIColor greenColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some code to decide how to choose the colour. This could be colours in an array and a mod (`%`) of the index path row to choose the index in the array. You then want to use either the `textColor` or the `attributedText` property of the label to set (attributed) text including the colour.